# iOS Safari Javascript setTimeout Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, settimeout

I have got an issue with the javascript method setTimeout() executing correctly on mobile safari.

My code is as follows:

```
function addBlock() {
  if(i < full) {
    $('#box-'+i).removeClass('empty');
    $('#box-'+i).addClass('full');
    i++;
    setTimeout(addBlock, 20);
  }
  else {
    if(fullcheck != Math.round(fullcheck)) {
      i = i++;
      $('#box-'+i).removeClass('empty');
//      $('#box-'+i).addClass('halfbox');

      $('#total-count').animate({height: barheight}, 5000);

    }
    if(usergiven) {
      $('#box-'+randbox).css('border', '1px SOLID #FF0000');  
      $('#box-'+randbox).css('background-color', '#FF0000');  
    }
  }
}
```

No matter what timeout value I provide the setTimeout function with, it always seems to run at the same speed.

The idea is that it populates a set of blocks at a faster speed than 1 every 2 seconds ( the actual amount should be about 50 a second iirc ).

Can anyone tell me why the mobile safari is not properly executing this function or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things that are hard to reason with regarding this question. One is the amount of variables without declaration or expressions without comments on what they should do (as in `fullcheck != Math.round(fullcheck)`. WTF!?), the other is how this code behaves as opposed to how you would like to have it behave.

Since the code is incomplete and not runnable one just has to guess as to what you mean. I am guessing you are saying that the code completes in about two seconds as it is now, and you would like it to complete in fifty seconds.

Without knowing the values of `i` and `full` it is impossible to do any calculations on the right timeouts, so I have to guess what you are doing wrong. With the current rate of 20ms in the timeout, you will process about 500 rows per second. If it currently runs in two seconds, that means you have 4000 rows. If they should be filled in fifty seconds, you will have to up your timeout to 500ms.

Comment: Thanks, this question isn't really relevant anymore, but as far as I remember this wasn't actually my code, I was posting this for someone else. I've accepted your answer as youve taken the time out to answer it. Thanks!